# How do I make the refresh action occur after the touch is released from the refresh control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am implementing `UIRefreshControl` on a `UITableView` to refresh the table's data. On other pull-to-refresh implementations, the refresh process does not begin until the user's finger is lifted while in the pull's refresh distance. UIRefreshControl does not immediately seem like it has this customization.

My `UIRefreshControl init` code:

```objectivec
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

My `refresh:` code is fairly basic:

```objectivec
- (void)refresh:(id)sender {
    // Refresh code...
    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

How can I delay the `refresh:` function until the user removes their finger from the pull?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've also stuck with the same problem. I don't think that my approach is very nice, but seems like it works.

1. Init `UIRefreshControl`

   ```
   UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
   self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
   ```
2. Check state of `UIRefreshControl` when user finish dragging the table (`UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`)

   ```
   - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
   {    
       if( self.refreshControl.isRefreshing )
           [self refresh];
   }
   ```
3. Update table

   ```
   - (void)refresh
   {
       [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

       // TODO: Update here your items

       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This solution works if the user slowly does the drag and pull. If it's almost like a flick, the loading wheel will run but the refresh: function won't be called until the table is moved again.

edit: I changed the function to scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and it seems to work fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are quite right! Now it works much better, thanks for correcting my code!)

Comment: There is a slight issue with this. If you pull the table view down enough to refresh, keep your finger down, go back up to where the spinner is roughly half visible, then let go...it will show the spinner spinning and nothing will happen.

Comment: @CameronAskew, this behaviour can be fixed by calling the same code as in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` also inside of the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method. But in this case we will also have to close refresh control by calling `setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)` of our `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`.

Answer (score 20):

`UIRefreshControl` already has accommodations for starting at the "right" time. The correct behavior for a pull-to-refresh control is to start the refresh after the user has crossed some "far enough" threshold, not when the user has released their drag.

In order to accomplish this, you need to modify your `-refresh:` method to check for when the control has transitioned into the `refreshing` state:

```
-(void)refresh:(id)sender {
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = (UIRefreshControl *)sender;
    if(refreshControl.refreshing) {
        (... refresh code ...)
    }
}
```

Note that any method you call for your `(... refresh code ...)` should be asynchronous, so that your UI doesn't freeze. You should change to main queue and call `-endRefreshing` at the end of your `(... refresh code ...)` block, instead of at the end of `-refresh:`:

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender {
    __weak UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = (UIRefreshControl *)sender;
    if(refreshControl.refreshing) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            /* (... refresh code ...) */
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [refreshControl endRefreshing];
                //reload the table here, too
            });
        });
    }
}
```

---

Changing the control event to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` will not work because `UIRefreshControl` is not a UI component intended to be directly interacted with. The user will never *touch* the `UIRefreshControl`, so no `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event can be triggered.

Comment: it's not working.
refresh method only called once, before the user lift his finger (tested with ios 10.2)

Comment: The behavior of `UIRefreshControl` has changed in the past 5 years. The "normal" implementation (what was described in the question) now behaves correctly, assuming the work of refreshing does not block the main thread. This is the behavior that matches system refresh controls (e.x. the one in Mail). Beginning refresh in `-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` is not.

Answer (score 5):

Scheduling the refresh to only occur when the finger has lifted can be achieved by using `NSRunLoop`. Call `-(void)performInModes:(NSArray<NSRunLoopMode> *)modes block:(void (^)(void))block;` with `NSRunLoopDefaultMode` in the array.

While the touch is still held, the runloop mode is `UITrackingRunLoopMode`, it will only go back to the default after liftoff.